# TeamCity cleanup rules not applying

Tags: teamcity

I am currently trying to setup some automation on TeamCity and am having issue with cleanup rules not seeming to apply to artifacts.

Currently my  are set to everything is cleaned up after 7 days, this seems to apply to everything apart from one artifact folder.

The folder structure is like this:

[image]

I've tried a couple of things from setting the artifact cleanup rules for this automation separately however there's still screenshots dating back to January in the folder.

I've tried setting artifact pattern to +:** which I thought would delete everything if it applied to the rules but I'm thinking it might be something to do with folder structure.

Any help on the correct cleanup settings that could fix this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: Leave the clean-up artifact pattern empty, it automatically applies to everything. How is your artifact path set up for the build configuration, the one that controls what gets copied into the artifacts folder in the first place?

Comment: stories/results => results, 
stories/results/report.html

Is what the artifact path are in build config, is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking of. So everything in stories/results from the build gets moved to artifacts/results. Do you know if the screenshots folder is in the original stores/results folder or if it's copied to the artifacts/results folder by part of the build script rather than the TeamCity artifacts config. Basically I'm thinking if something else copied the folder in there then it might be a permissions issue?

Comment: If you've got access, have a look under - **Administration> Diagnostics> Server Logs> teamcity-server.log**. If there are errors during the cleanup you might see them logged there.

Comment: Hmm it is odd, no errors are thrown. It runs: Applying policy: clean ARTIFACTS more than 14 days older than the last build; artifact patterns: +:**/* then just seems to think it's done and there's still a 2gb folder full of screenshots.

Comment: Could there be another build that has an artifact or snapshot dependency on these builds?

Comment: It has dependencies on other builds but nothing on it unless I can't find it in another project.

Comment: And they're not pinned? The last thing I can think to try is setting the explicit artifact removal path to `+:**/results/screenshots/*` and then because it's newline separated `+:**/*` on the next line?

Comment: I've noticed something odd aswell in the builds, the only step that has this issue with artifact cleanup seems to change its artifact dependency every time it's run.

Comment: I think it has no relevance actually, it just changes dependencies to the latest artifacts from another build.
Just thought it might be the cause because no other build shows it but I don't think it is

Comment: If you look at the Build chain tab for one of the builds that should have been cleaned up it might highlight any dependencies that are preventing the clean-up. I can't think of anything else that might cause this behaviour I'm afraid.